# About using For-each loop in jsp but without using jstl tags?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to perform paging to show the data from database ,RecordsShow is the class which show the all records and I take a List in which these records are store .

```
for(RecordsShow s : (RecordsShow)list) {
}
```

but it gives error for-each not applicable to expression type....

Comment: please provide some more explanation . or elaborate your problem

Comment: what is `RecordsShow` here?

Comment: why don't you want to use JSTL? why are you going back in stone age?

Comment: @Braj yes you are right will update my answer using `jstl` might help him

Answer (score 0):

From the error you posted ,

> for-each not applicable to expression type

For-each loop is applicable for arrays and Iterable.

And while iterating , if the list is of objects of `RecordsShow` class, you can simply iterate no need to cast it into the list again.

```
for(RecordsShow s : ListName) {
  . . .
}
```

or you can do it easily with `c:forEach`

add the `taglib`,

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

and then,

```
<c:forEach items='${List}' var='varName'>
  <c:out>${varname.List}</c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: please post us the code how you are adding the elements into the `list` and also the stactraces

Answer (score 0):

If the list object here is a list of RecordShow object, i.e. list, then you can use:

```
for(RecordsShow s : list) {
}
```

Comment: How that differentiates from my answer ?